# R how to get the third and last row for each user

Tags: r

I have a table that has information about certain users. What I'm trying to do is extract the third and last row of each user...How would I do that? So for example:

```
User | num |

use1 | 3 |

use1 | 2 |

use1 | 5 |

use1 | 8 |

use1 | 6 |

use2 | 1 |

..
```

So in this example, I'd want the row with `num = 5` and `num = 6` and this would continue for each different user in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For variety, here is a `plyr` solution:

```
library(plyr)

#group by user and return 3rd and last row
ddply(df, .(User), function(x) x[c(3, nrow(x)),])
```

Comment: People still use plyr?

Comment: Sure why not? It's not like it stopped working. I never really got into dplyr because it didn't seem to offer anything more for what I do.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
library(dplyr)

# Assuming df is your sample data
df %>% group_by(User) %>% filter(row_number() %in% c(3, n()))
```

Comment: In what way?  Works here with dplyr 0.4.3

Comment: @jkeirstead - can confirm it does work. Having said that - `df %>% group_by(user) %>% slice(c(3, n()))` might be more succinct

Comment: `slice`!  I always forget about `slice`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a data.table solution  like this:

```
library(data.table)

dt  = data.table("user" = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,5)),"num" = c(3,2,5,8,6,10:6))

dt[, "row" := 1:.N, by =.(user)]

> dt[ , .(Num = 3,.N), by = .(user)]
   user Num N
1:    1   3 5
2:    2   3 5
```

Comment: is dt suppose to be the variable storing my table and If i already have that variable do I have to include the second line?

Comment: @jim so if you have a data.frame load in the data.table package and run 'setDT(yourdataframename) and then run it like above

Comment: @jim it looks like your dataframe is named df. so you could run `setDT(df) and then swap out dt with df and it will all work. If your data.frame is really big, data.table will be the fastest solution.

Comment: Shouldn't there be 4 rows in the result? And it seems like `dt[dt[, .I[c(3, .N)], by = user]$V1]` would be easier.

Comment: @RichScriven yah that would work too. I think what is written is easier to follow what's happening though.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `base R`

```
i1 <- with(data, as.logical(ave(seq_along(User), User, FUN = 
           function(x) seq_along(x) %in% c(3, length(x) & length(x) > 3))))
data[i1,]
```